# Recommendations on tracking user browsing with Django

Tags: django, logging, client, tracking

I'm developing a large scale consumer site with django for my masters project. Basically, I would like to track everything that a user searches for/clicks on etc, so as to make recommendations a'la amazon's "recommended for you" sections.

Are there any good resources for doing this? I don't know whether I should be storing this in logs, or in a model, or what. I've never done anything like this before.

I'm having trouble finding many resources to help me on this, perhaps because I don't really know what to even search for, so any suggestions or nudges in a direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: It's really up to you. You could store it in a `Searches` model, a plaintext file, logs, really anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using exactly this to keep a track of all my user and their activity,

```
class ActivityLog(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    act_meta = HStoreField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

'act-meta' stores all the details particular to that user event. Since i didn't want this everywhere on my website, i'm not using it via middleware. But i'm using this for a recommendation system and it works just fine.

Comment: Have you seen this package: https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It seems pretty similar to what you're doing. I appreciate the response!

Comment: I think I'm likely to end up doing something similar to what you've done here

Comment: yeah, i checked a few (including this) while developing. But i needed a very particular solution for my site, therefore i collected concepts from here and there (this too) and created a custom soln. What i've provided you in the ans is a very general concept you'll find in every activity tracker package.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like I will likely roll my own as well

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a middlware that can take requests and responses then store them to a database table..you can store everything such such as path, files, all what you need.

Comment: You ussualy want to put only references and small data in database, to offload it ;) so files ( like large files ) aren't good idea to store :)